# Javascript drop down menu with keyboard navigation

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can arrow key navigation be done using just JS alone?

Not third party like superfish,etc.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217553/detecting-arrow-key-press-in-ie-via-javascript-jquery it gives examples of how to detect arrowkey keypress.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here is a skeleton:

```
document.onkeydown = function(evt) 
{
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.keyCode == 37) 
    {
        //do something
    }
    else if (evt.keyCode == 38) 
    {
        //do something
    }
    else if (evt.keyCode == 39) 
    {
        //do something
    }
    else if (evt.keyCode == 40) 
    {
        //do something
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get away with this:

```
document.onkeypress = keyHandler;

function keyHandler(evt)
{
    var evt  = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
    var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null);

    if (evt.keyCode == 37 /*left arrow*/) {
        //...
    }
    if (evt.keyCode == 38 /*up arrow*/) {
        //...
    }
    if (evt.keyCode == 39 /*right arrow*/) {
        //...
    }
    if (evt.keyCode == 40 /*down arrow*/) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Of course, there are some [quirks](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html)...

Comment: Ugh, those quirks are a killer. I once thought that you could build your own textbox in JavaScript, but when I saw that in Opera you cannot distinguish between, say, `Delete` and `.`...

Comment: how would i move the pointer to the selected list item up and down?