# Javascript up arrow keypress not firing

Tags: javascript, keypress

I've been doing some JS recently and getting this stupid error, I can detect the return key using `e.keyCode` and checking for `keyCode == 13` but when I try to check for `38` (Up arrow) it never fires. Any help please?

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="TxtMessage" 
       placeholder="Message" onKeyPress="SendMsg(event)" >
```

Javascript:

```
function SendMsg(e)
{
var message = document.getElementById("TxtMessage");

if(e.keyCode ==13)
{
    var json = {"message": message.value};
    json = JSON.stringify(json);
    ws.send(json);
    PreviousMessage = message.value;
    message.value = "";
    message.focus();
}
else if(e.keyCode == 38) 
{ 
    message.value = PreviousMessage;
}
}
```

EDIT: Fixed by changing onKeyPress to onKeyDown... Strange.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? What should happen when you press ENTER and UP?

Comment: When up is pressed it sets the text of an element to the previous sent message. But the up arrow key press event isn't getting fired. I tried putting an alert there and it still didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Replace your following lines:

```
if(e.keyCode !=13) return;
if(e.keyCode == 38) { message.value = PreviousMessage; return;  }
```

for this one:

```
var charCode = typeof e.which == "number" ? e.which : e.keyCode;

if(charCode == 38) { message.value = PreviousMessage; return;  }
if(charCode !=13) return;
```

**UPDATE:**
My above code still didn't work when used in keypress event, as the **correct solution** is to use **keydown** or **keyup** events to catch the arrow keys. See here for an enhanced answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2218915/352672  Also see here a [**working jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/s63MR/) using the keyup event.

Answer (score 1):

Swap

```
if(e.keyCode !=13) return;
```

and the next line.

Comment: You sure? Maybe problem is somewhere else? By "didn't work" you mean that `message.value` is not set correctly?

Comment: Yes, I've been using alerts aswell to double check it's firing. The alerts are never shown.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
function SendMsg(e)
{
    var message = document.getElementById("TxtMessage");

    // Load previous message
    if(e.keyCode == 38) { message.value = PreviousMessage; return;  }


    // Send message on ENTER
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        if(message.value !=null && message.value !="")
        {
            var json = {"message": message.value};
            json = JSON.stringify(json);
            ws.send(json);
            PreviousMessage = message.value;
            message.value = "";
            message.focus();
        }
        else
        {
            CAlert("Message cannot be empty.", false, true);    
        }
    }
}
```

**Update** Why keyDown works and keyPress doesn't?

> Note that keydown and keyup provide a code indicating which key is
>   pressed, while keypress indicates which character was entered. For
>   example, a lowercase "a" will be reported as 65 by keydown and keyup,
>   but as 97 by keypress. An uppercase "A" is reported as 65 by all
>   events. Because of this distinction, when catching special keystrokes
>   such as arrow keys, .keydown() or .keyup() is a better choice.

In short, `keyPress` event won't fire for arrow keys.

Comment: I need to check this, it makes sure that the message is only sent when enter is pressed and not other keys. I tried completely removing the check for 13 and just having the e.keyCode == 38 and I put an alert inside the { but it still didn't fire...

Comment: Just updated the Javascript in the original post to my new one which still doesn't work and fixes what you're trying to say is a problem.